# Coq Qed raise a warning with admitted lemmas

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

When developing a big system in Coq, I usually admit many lemmas and see whether the important theorem works or not, and then solve lemmas one by one.

Coq accepts `Qed.` even with admitted lemmas, so sometimes I'm not 100% sure whether I solve all the admits and need to seek help with text search `admit` and `Admitted`, is there a more strict version of `Qed.` which doesn't allow theorems to be proved with admitted lemmas?

```
Print Assumptions lemma_names.
```

seems a feasible way to check, are there other solutions?

Comment: `Print Assumptions` on the main theorem is indeed the standard way to go. Also when it's your own admits that you want to check, looking for `Admitted` should suffice.